# PST to UTC parsing of time in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to convert the time from PST to UTC timezone but seeing some unexpected result, while IST to UTC is working fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    const longForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05 MST"
    t, err := time.Parse(longForm, "2016-01-17 20:04:05 IST")
    fmt.Println(t, err)
    fmt.Printf("IST to UTC: %v\n\n", t.UTC())

    s, err1 := time.Parse(longForm, "2016-01-17 23:04:05 PST")
    fmt.Println(s, err1)
    fmt.Printf("PST to UTC: %v\n\n", s.UTC())

}
```

Output is :

```
2016-01-17 20:04:05 +0530 IST <nil>
IST to UTC: 2016-01-17 14:34:05 +0000 UTC

2016-01-17 23:04:05 +0000 PST <nil>
PST to UTC: 2016-01-17 23:04:05 +0000 UTC
```

When parsing is done for IST, it shows **+0530**, while for PST shows **+0000** and in UTC it print same value of HH:MM:SS (23:04:05) as in PST. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this:
https://play.golang.org/p/Oxn6863SQa

Comment: Is this bug or I am not using the API in proper way?

Comment: On my system, The result is fine for IST as my timezone is in IST. But on golang server as this is default in UTC, IST result is messing up.

Comment: PST seems to be ambiguous. Is it Pacific Standard Time or Philippine Standard Time?

Comment: It is Pacific Standard Time. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [time.Parse()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) says:

> If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset. This choice means that such a time can be parsed and reformatted with the same layout losslessly, but the exact instant used in the representation will differ by the actual zone offset. To avoid such problems, prefer time layouts that use a numeric zone offset, or use ParseInLocation.

Here is how to use `ParseInLocation`:

```
IST, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
PST, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

const longForm = "2006-01-02 15:04:05 MST"
t, err := time.ParseInLocation(longForm, "2016-01-17 20:04:05 IST", IST)
fmt.Println(t, err)
fmt.Printf("IST to UTC: %v\n\n", t.UTC())

s, err1 := time.ParseInLocation(longForm, "2016-01-17 23:04:05 PST", PST)
fmt.Println(s, err1)
fmt.Printf("PST to UTC: %v\n\n", s.UTC())
```

Output:

```
2016-01-17 20:04:05 +0530 IST <nil>
IST to UTC: 2016-01-17 14:34:05 +0000 UTC

2016-01-17 23:04:05 -0800 PST <nil>
PST to UTC: 2016-01-18 07:04:05 +0000 UTC
```

[Full code on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iLtZkyRYxW)

Comment: In addition to this, does above code will take care of PDT timezone also which is 1 hour earlier than PST or I need to explicitly convert timezone from PST to PDT or there is any direct way to convert from X timezone too PDT?

Comment: @CodeQuestor time.Location handles Daylight Saving Time changes.

Comment: This is a great answer, but for me your comment below the question was the most valueable: "PST seems to be ambiguous. Is it Pacific Standard Time or Philippine Standard Time?". You may consider mentioning this in your answer as well, because it sheds light on _why_ PST in the string in insufficient for `Parse` and it is necessary to use `ParseInLocation` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [time.Parse()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) says:

> If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset. This choice means that such a time can be parsed and reformatted with the same layout losslessly, but the exact instant used in the representation will differ by the actual zone offset. To avoid such problems, prefer time layouts that use a numeric zone offset, or use ParseInLocation.

So, the system doesn't know what "PST" is. For me, the system also doesn't know what IST is. You can check for supported locations like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for _, name := range []string{"MST", "UTC", "IST", "PST", "EST", "PT"} {
        loc, err := time.LoadLocation(name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("No location", name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Location", name, "is", loc)
        }
    }
}
```

Output on my system:

```
Location MST is MST
Location UTC is UTC
No location IST
No location PST
Location EST is EST
No location PT
```